# How do I retrieve answers that I deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Sometimes I delete an  answer of mine to a question because some later answer is better.
The problem is that I then often forget who gave that better answer and the quickest way to recover the answer might be through  a list of my deleted answers.
Do I have access to such a list or more generally to a list of all deleted answers classified, say,  by subjects or authors or whatever criterion ?

**Edit**
Ah, I see that the first option [in this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/15239/3217) is the better one since it allows you to retrieve ALL the deleted answers, whereas the second option only gives you the recent suppressions.
Thanks to all the commmenters.

Comment: [A related meta.SE thread.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105835)

Comment: Main > Activity > Answers > View more > deleted recent answers // That is how I usually find any answers that I have deleted, but I am unsure of how "recent answers" is quantified. Maybe someone else will know, but that list (i.e., deleted recent answers) usually does the trick for me.

Comment: The accepted answer there is no longer completely true, but [2mkgz's answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/15239) is pretty much up-to-date.

Comment: Many thanks to all the commenters. It would be great if the procedure were explained somewhere in the Help Center.